# Ruby on Rails passing a salt to Digest::SHA512

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, digest-authentication, sha512

what is the equivalent in Rails of this (PHP):

```
 hash_hmac('sha512', $password . $salt, $siteSalt);
```

I got as far as this:

```
Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(password + salt)
```

But have no idea how to incorporate the site salt into the equation, all online examples I've seen do not pass the salt to the hexdigest method. When I've tried it I get an error for too many arguments.

And this notation with a colon (which I saw somewhere):

```
salted = password + salt
Digest::SHA512.hexdigest("#{salted}:site_salt")
```

Doesn't produce the same hash.

Thanks

**Edit**
I stumbled upon this that looks closer to what I need (sorry, I'm very new to the whole hashing thing):

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha512', site_salt, salted)
```

But it still produces a different hash than the one stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
HMAC::SHA512.hexdigest(site_salt, password + salt)
```

It looks like the PHP code you're referencing is using the siteSalt as the key for the HMAC function, with the password and salt concatenated specified as the value to be hashed.

I checked this by running this code in PHP:

```
% php -r 'print hash_hmac("sha512", "password" . "salt", "siteSalt") . "\n";'
15b45385a00b10eb25c3aa8198d747862575a796a89a6c79b5a0b8ea332a8d75b1ec0dc1f0c9f7930d30c9359279e86df29067bbbc5d9bcf87839f855ac7a677
```

And then in the Rails shell:

```
>> HMAC::SHA512.hexdigest('siteSalt', 'password' + 'salt')
=> "15b45385a00b10eb25c3aa8198d747862575a796a89a6c79b5a0b8ea332a8d75b1ec0dc1f0c9f7930d30c9359279e86df29067bbbc5d9bcf87839f855ac7a677"
```

Comment: yes, that's pretty much what I had in the last method. Turns out the salt was empty in the PHP code, hence the discrepancy. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Rails code didn't compile for me (not surprising using Rails 4,  3 years later). So for anyone finding this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rails 4 and @brian's rails code didn't compile for me.

Here is what worked for me.

Rails shell:

```
2.1.2 :001 > Digest::HMAC.hexdigest("password"+"salt","siteSalt",Digest::SHA512)
 => "15b45385a00b10eb25c3aa8198d747862575a796a89a6c79b5a0b8ea332a8d75b1ec0dc1f0c9f7930d30c9359279e86df29067bbbc5d9bcf87839f855ac7a677"
```

PHP (from command line)

```
 $ php -r 'print hash_hmac("sha512", "password" . "salt", "siteSalt") . "\n";'
15b45385a00b10eb25c3aa8198d747862575a796a89a6c79b5a0b8ea332a8d75b1ec0dc1f0c9f7930d30c9359279e86df29067bbbc5d9bcf87839f855ac7a677
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the salt was empty in the PHP code, hence the discrepancy. But now both methods return the same.